# Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I am having Ubuntu 18.10. I cannot install any application from Ubuntu software. First it installs it 15%. Then it gave me an error:

> Cannot install <package name> Cannot perform the following tasks:

I have tried `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, all are running good. Also I have reinstalled this thing 3 times but nothing good.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  What version of Ubuntu are you using?   You say Ubuntu 18.10, but have tagged 18.04 ?

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  Ubuntu 18.10 is a development release and off-topic on this site (please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).  You should seek help on #ubuntu+1 [irc] on freenode (see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList), and if you believe you have found a bug report it (`ubuntu-bug` or for help see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs, but I'd suggest checking with others first as I've been using 18.10 for some time; am right now)

Comment: How about 18.04

Comment: I have the updated it yesterday but the problem is  there before there weeks..

Comment: You'll have to give us some actual examples of a problem, you can use any program/package you've tried to install & failed at but I'll use the example package "gedit" (gnome text editor).  Please edit your question and provide the following command & results (`apt-cache policy gedit`)